# PayPal Button in android not working

Tags: javascript, android, paypal, in-app-purchase, titanium

I am trying this code for android to add a pay-pal button but it is giving errors.I think the error is because this code was for Iphone and i am using it for android.Does any one have code for android paypal button.The code is as follows

```
 var PayPal = require('ti.paypal');
     var paypalButton = Titanium.Paypal.createPaypalButton({
     appId:"APP-XXXXXXXXXXX",
     width:100,
  height:30,
  buttonStyle:Titanium.Paypal.BUTTON_68x24,
  paypalEnvironment:Titanium.Paypal.PAYPAL_ENV_SANDBOX,
  feePaidByReceiver:false,
  transactionType:Titanium.Paypal.PAYMENT_TYPE_SERVICE,
  enableShipping:true,
    payment: 
  {
    amount: 15.00,
    tax: 0.00,
    shipping: 5.00,
    currency: "GBP",
    recipient: "test@mail.com",
    itemDescription: "Test",
    senderEmailOrPhone:'test@mail'
    //merchantName: Titanium.App.Properties.getString('storeName')
    }
  });
```

and i am adding this in tiapp.xml

```
  <module platform="android" version="2.2.1">ti.paypal</module>
```

Comment: you shouldn't just change iphone to android. It is been made platform specific

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is an publicly open module for PayPal for both android and iOS. Just download this version:

```
https://marketplace.appcelerator.com/apps/780?1115227925
```

Not sure where you got your version 2.2.1 from. Either from the future, or some other place.

Comment: 2.2.1 is actually the latest Android specific version from Appcelerator. If you download the module from the Marketplace, and look inside, you'll see 2.2.1 for Android. https://marketplace.appcelerator.com/apps/780?283565719

Answer (score 0):

You should open up the example provided in modules/android/ti.paypal/2.2.1/example/simple.js and compare it to your code. The biggest error you have is trying to do "Titanium.Paypal", when you are loading the module in to "var PayPal". Past that, there have been API changes since the version that your sample is based on. Your best bet would be to throw out what you have, and start from the example that best fits your needs (simple, chained, parallel, or pre-approval).